# 'npm run dev' vs 'next build' tsx code compilation restriction different level

Tags: reactjs, npm, azure-devops, next.js

I use this command to run the server locally:

```sh
npm run dev
```

On test instance in https://dev.azure.com/ on 'npm install and build' with the same code I get many compilation errors. For example:

> Type error: 'children' are specified twice. The attribute named
> 'children' will be overwritten.

When I change file from `tsx` to `jsx`, there are no errors.

What command should I use locally to get the same compilation restriction level?

Is this some warn as error strategy?

Comment: Hi there, is there any updates for this issue? I have investigated about warn as error strategy but found no information on it. Have you tried the method below? Please feel free to let me know whether my answer can help you.

Comment: I do not check this yet, but in my situation yarn on dev.azure use babel/plugin-syntax-typescript@^7.2.0

I will try install locally npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-syntax-typescript@^7.2.0

Comment: Look forward to hearing your good news~

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error may be related to the TypeScript version.

You can try changing your local TypeScript version based on the TypeScript version of the Microsoft-hosted agent to see if you can get the same error locally.

If you are using `windows-latest` or `windows-2019`:

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript  16.8.30509.167
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.4.0 16.0.30509.167

If you are using `vs2017-win2016`:

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript  15.9.28125.51
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.2.0 15.8.27729.1
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.2.1 15.8.27729.1
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.2.2 15.8.27729.1
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.2.3 15.8.27729.1
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.3.1 15.0.28218.60